# rails 3 swf_upload InvalidAuthenticityToken and sending cookie session

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, swfupload, middleware

I have a swfupload working with paperclip on rails 3 (finally!) 
I turned off the autehnticitytoken with the following line in my controller:

```
skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, :only => :create
```

I know am trying to get sessions working (flash doesn't send this)
Of course i googled my ass of but no luck so far. 
this is what i have in my view (part of it)

```
'<%= u session_key_name %>' : encodeURIComponent('<%= u cookies[session_key_name] %>'),
'authenticity_token' : '<%= form_authenticity_token %>',
'gallerie_id' : '<%= params[:gallery_id] %>'
```

So i send the session key with the post data. I have to "catch" those params with some middleware code.

```
require 'rack/utils'

class FlashSessionCookieMiddleware
  def initialize(app, session_key = '_session_id')
    @app = app
    @session_key = session_key
  end

  def call(env)
    if env['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] =~ /^(Adobe|Shockwave) Flash/
      req = Rack::Request.new(env)
      env['HTTP_COOKIE'] = [ @session_key,
                             req.params[@session_key] ]
                           .join('=').freeze unless req.params[@session_key].nil?
      env['HTTP_ACCEPT'] = "#{req.params['_http_accept']}"
                           .freeze unless req.params['_http_accept'].nil?
    end
    @app.call(env)
  end
end
```

can anybody help me! really stuck now!

Comment: http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=40591

Answer (score 1):

It's probably because "session_key" changed to just "key". Below is this update that works for me.

```
require 'rack/utils'
class FlashSessionCookieMiddleware
  def initialize(app, key = '_MYAPP_session')
    @app = app
    @key = (key || '_MYAPP_session')
  end

  def call(env)
    if env['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] =~ /^(Adobe|Shockwave) Flash/
      params = ::Rack::Utils.parse_query(env['QUERY_STRING'])
      unless params[@key].nil?
        env['HTTP_COOKIE'] = "#{@key}=#{params[@key]}".freeze
        # puts "env['HTTP_COOKIE'] #{env['HTTP_COOKIE'].inspect}"
      end
    end
    @app.call(env)
  end
end
```

Also, you'll want to check to make sure your javascript is using the "key" instead of "session_key" for `ActionController::Base.session_options[:key]` when setting your javascript variable.